# How to create permisison based on user group in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, authorization

I am using codeigniter ion authentication for user group maintenance

[Here's](http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/) link for ion authenticaiton documentation

In Edit user group i would like to add menus to access for particular group alone. how to design a mysql table and access it in our controller and view page to restrict page based on user group.
Please check with the below image[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created menu table and menu permission table seperately.

```
menu table
   menu id
    menu name
menu permission table
 id 
menuid 
usergroup_id
```

Check whether the current logged in user group id is available in menu permission table or not

```
public function get_menus($user_group_id) {
    if ($user_group_id == 1) {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM menus where parent_id=0");
        $get_results = $query->result();
    } else {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM menu_permissions where user_group_id = $user_group_id");
        $get_results = $query->result();
        $user_perm = array();
        foreach($get_results as $key=> $get_perm){
            // echo $get_results[$key]->menu_id;
            ////print '<pre>';
            $user_perm[] = $get_results[$key]->menu_id;
        }
        $user_perm = implode(', ', $user_perm);
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM menus WHERE id IN (".$user_perm.")");
        $get_results = $query->result();
    } 
    //print_r($get_results);
    /*$user_perm = array();
    foreach($get_results as $key=> $get_perm){
        // echo $get_results[$key]->menu_id;
        ////print '<pre>';

         $user_perm[] = $get_results[$key]->menu_id;
     }*/
     return $get_results;
}
```